# Interpolating point on a quad

Tags: interpolation

I have a quad defined by four arbitrary points, A, B, C and D all on the same plane. I then have a known point on that quad, P.

[image: The quad ABCD]

I want to find the value of 's' as shown in the diagram above, where t and s are parametric values in the range (0, 1) that interpolate along the edges.

Comment: The line containing $P$ isn't parallel to anything?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808441/inverse-bilinear-interpolation and http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/ibilinear/ibilinear.htm

Comment: @J.M., it seems the OP is assuming [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) on the quad.

Comment: Ah yes, inverse bilinear interpolation is what I'm talking about - guess that makes this a duplicate question

Comment: Possibly interestingly related: _["What is this technique, if not bilinear interpolation?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24019709/405017)_

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the point you show on $AB$ and $F$ be the point on $CD$.  Then $E=A+t(B-A), F=C+t(D-C), P=E+s(F-E)$, where you can write these out componentwise.